# jquery validate: focusCleanup: true and focusInvalid: false don't work as expected

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using Joern's [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) 1.6.

My goal is to have the following behavior: remove the error message for an element once the user focuses it. From what I understand setting 'focusCleanup: true' should take care of this.

However (at least on my browser (Firefox 3.5.7 on Linux)), I only get the desired behavior (ie, error message for a field disappearing once you focus it) if I **click** into the field; it doesn't handle **tabbing** into the field correctly.

Sample code:

HTML:

```
   <form id='abc' name='abc'>
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1"/>
    <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value='submit'/> 
    </form>
```

JS:

```
   $("#abc").validate({
   focusCleanup: true,
   focusInvalid: false,

    rules: {t1: {required: true, email:true}, t2: {required: true,email:true}}
});
```

I am setting 'focusInvalid: false' because the docs say one should avoid combining focusCleanup and focusInvalid; in my experience commenting out that line makes no difference.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please let us know if the solution for this problem was found. If Nick's answer solved the issue, then accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 8):

What you are experiencing is the correct behavior, just maybe a bit counter-intuitive.  [You can see your code in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/QPxFe/).  When you click, you're **only** focusing the textbox, however when you tab you're causing 2 events that matter, you're triggering both `focusin` *and* `keyup`.

Since you're triggering the `keyup` what's happening is it **is** clearing the error, but because you're typing something in they box (it doesn't distinguish tab from any other key, like a letter)...but then it's re-evaluating whether the box is valid on every `keyup`, displaying the same error as before since the tab didn't have any effect on that...since it didn't add any text.

If you want to disable `onkeyup` validation it'll stop doing that, like this:

```
$("#abc").validate({
  focusCleanup: true,
  rules: {t1: {required: true, email:true}, t2: {required: true,email:true}},
  onkeyup: false,
});​
```

[For comparison, here's that code in a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QPxFe/1/), so you can compare it with the original demo above.

Comment: Is there a way (without editing the plugin) to swap `keyup` for `change` so that validation can still be triggered when the user types/deletes something but won't be triggered when they tab-in or press up/down to select autocomplete options?