# jQuery Validate Text Field On Blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, onblur

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

I'm having a problem which is causing the validation to start when the user starts typing however this is not what I want.
I want to the validation to start after the user leaves the text field.
Here is my code:

```
    <input class="required email" type="text" size="26" name="usernameField" id="usernameField" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#usernameField").validate({
           onfocusout:false
          });


   });

</script>
```

I thought using the onfocusout option would work but it's still validating as the user types.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation says that onkeyup is true by default.  If you disable this and leave onfocusout set to true, it should work.

Comment: As @CDirty suggested, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786021/using-jquery-validate-plugin-onfocusout-onkeyup-notworking-as-expected-on-prod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to validate onblur:

#### jQuery

```
$("#Email").blur(function() 
{
 var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;  
 var emailaddress = $("#Email").val();
 if(!emailReg.test(emailaddress)) 
    $("#emailspan").html('<font color="#cc0000">Please enter valid Email address</font>');  
 else
    $("#emailspan").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');  
});
```

#### HTML

```
<h4>
<br />Email <span id="star5">*</span>
</h4>                       
<input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" maxLength="50" size="45" /><span id="emailspan" value="0"></span>
```