# Rails model apply validations based on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, global-variables

Due to some issues, I've been working with a system which used a model in many pages, where its validation of its the model contents vary due to the controller steps.

E.g. when the @step = 1, the model should validates_precense_of :name, but you only validates_precense_of :age until @step =2

However, since the rails model can't read session or global variables, how can I apply this ?

Comment: `@step` isn't a global, but that aside, isn't the step part of the model? If not, why can't it be? It doesn't need to be persisted, just make it a pseudo-attribute.

Comment: No, basically, I have many views that uses cross model attributes, for example, first view will require some driver info of :name, wheras second view will require user to enter age. when I submit the first view, I want the model to validate :name, but not validate age, since its not required until the second view. but when I click submit for the second view, I def want to validates age

Comment: what is the @step? Is it a model? A variable to determine the view? What does @step do in the app?

edit: you answered before i put this comment...

Comment: Since @step is nothing more than a cue to change the view, you could just use javascript to display the different divs containing each attribute based on the step you are on and when all fields are filled, have it submit.

Comment: @phil88530 I understand that. What I'm saying is that you can use a flag in the model to indicate which step you're on, and on that basis, define your validations.

Comment: I found this answer [Jquery Validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202759/jquery-validate-text-field-on-blur) that seems to do what you are looking for. Looking at the documentation for the JQuery Validation plugin, it can track presence of fields and what is put in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what Dave is saying is

```
class Model 
  attr_accessor :step
  validate_presence_of :name, if: { |m| m.step == 1 }
  validate_presence_of :age, if: { |m| m.step == 2 }
end

class Controller
  def first_step
    @model = Model.new(params[:model].merge(step: 1))
    if @model.valid?
   ....
  end
  def second_step
    @model.update_attributes(params[:model].merge(step: 2))
    if @model.valid?
   ....
  end
end
```