# onkeyup and onfocusout is not working in jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin for the validation purpose. I have to real time validation on the form.
For example if a **first name** is required, then user should get the required message for first time and goes when he start to type in the text box.

To achieve this functionality I am using on `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` options of the plugin.
For this I refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786021/using-jquery-validate-plugin-onfocusout-onkeyup-notworking-as-expected-on-prod) who has the same issue.

Here is my **coffeescript** code for form validation

```
defaultPageForm: (self)->
      form = $("#PageForm")
      if form.length > 0
        form.find('textarea').on 'click', -> $(@).valid()
        form.find('input').on    'click', -> $(@).valid()
        form.validate    

          ignore: ".ignore"                        
          rules:
            "view[name]":
              required: true
              NameWordCount: [3]


            "view[comment]":
              required: true
              CommentWordCount: [5]

            accept_terms: "required"

          messages:
            "view[comment]": "Please add comment"

          errorElement: "span"
          errorClass: "error_msg wide "
          errorPlacement: (error, element) ->
            element.siblings(".view_form_error_msg").remove()
            error.appendTo element.closest(".controls")              
            return

          ###### Real time validation code #############
          onkeyup: (element) -> 
            $(element).valid()  
            return        

          onfocusout: (element) -> 
            $(element).valid()  
            return 

          submitHandler: (form) ->
            self._setupData()
            self._submitForm(form)
            off

      return
```

But it not working fine. For example for testing purpose I added alert message under `onkeyup` but is nothing pop up also it not applying realtime validation.

Is there anything I am missing.
Here is my html

```
<input type="text" value="as as" size="50" placeholder="Full Name" name="view[name]" id="customerName" class="string required wide" style="font-size: 20.4572px; line-height: 49px;">
```

So how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: What exactly is _"not working fine"_ supposed to mean?  The `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` options are already enabled by default and don't need to be specified within `.validate()` unless you want to over-ride them for some reason.

Comment: I have updated my post and I need to display message for the first time.

Comment: You would not use the `.valid()` method within the `.validate()` method.  Refer to the source code of `onkeyup` and `onfocusout`.  Use `this.element(element)` instead of `$(element).valid()`.

Comment: Again, nobody knows what _"not working fine"_ is supposed to mean.  Please edit your OP accordingly.

Comment: Also tried with `this.element(element)` but it is not working

Comment: Working fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/ajy5j8jq/ ~  Your CoffeeScript might be screwing up something else.

Answer (score 11):

You would never use the `.valid()` method within the `.validate()` method. Refer to the source code of `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` to see how it's done.

Use `this.element(element)` instead of `$(element).valid()`

To over-ride the default functionality ("lazy validation") of `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` and use "eager" validation instead...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    onkeyup: function(element) {
        this.element(element);  // <- "eager validation"
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        this.element(element);  // <- "eager validation"
    }
    ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ajy5j8jq/**