# jQuery validation method (required: false) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation to validate my form fields. I've two fields, named "comment" and "account name". The comment field has a validation method where **required** is set to **false**. The account name field has a validation method where **required** is set to **true**. When the user clicks the submit button **without** entering any value on both fields, the comment field was not highlighted in green even though this field is **not required**. Why is that so?

[image: Picture of error]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();
                $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
                $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();
                $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#dataForm').validate({
        rules: {                
            accountNameInput: {
                required: true
            },
            commentInput: {
                required: false
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="#">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="commentInput">Comments</label>
        <textarea class="commentInput" id="commentInput" name="commentInput" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="accountNameInput">Account name</label>
        <input type="text" id="accountNameInput" name="accountNameInput"
               placeholder="Account name" class="form-control font-bold" value="" />
    </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />

    </form>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/gud7xjy0/

Comment: Since you are setting the "required" as false, the comment textbox is not getting the indicator. Isn't this the expected behavior?

Comment: This is jquery-validate, not jquery-validation-engine.

Comment: Unhighlighting is only used when an input goes from invalid to valid. If the field is not required, it's never invalid, so it doesn't change and never gets a highlight.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, sorry I got a little mixed up. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `commentInput` field is not "required", therefore this field will be totally ignored for validation whenever it's left empty.

However, you can programmatically force it to validate using the `.valid()` method whenever the submit is clicked.

```
$('#saveButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#commentInput').valid();  // <- force validation test on this field
});
```

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/gud7xjy0/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/gud7xjy0/6/)**

Optionally, you can also force this empty field to validate when you `focusout` of it...

```
// force eager validation on this one field
$('#commentInput').on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).valid();  
});
```

**Working DEMO 2: [jsfiddle.net/gud7xjy0/9/](https://jsfiddle.net/gud7xjy0/9/)**

However, this demo #2 does not make sense; since validation for the form is still "lazy" (*the other field will be ignored on `focusout` until the submit is clicked*).  Option #2 only makes sense when you [have your whole form setup to also implement "eager" style validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797083/594235).