# Start jquery Validate from first keypress

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery Validate to validate input

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules : {
        "name" : { 
            required : true,
            minlength : 10,
            maxlength : 50,
            alphanumeric: true
        }
    },
    messages : {
        "name" : {
            required : "Name is required!",
            minlength : "Enter number of characters between 10 and 50."
        }
    },
    success: function(label,element) {
        $("#errorMsgDiv").html("");
        },
    submitHandler : function(form) {
        form.submit(); 
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $("#errorMsgDiv").html("");
        error.appendTo('#errorMsgDiv'); 
    }
});
```

Text input on the jsp page is

```
<form:input path="name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Name" id="existingValue" required="required"/>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="errorMsgDiv">
```

Right now, the validation happens/ validation message comes only after changing focus from the text input.
How do I get the validation to run as soon as the first character is entered in the text and without waiting for the focus to change?

Comment: Which js you are using to validate?

Comment: @AppleOrange not sure I understand your question correctly, but im using jQuery Validation Plugin v1.17.0 from https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thank you. I tweaked your code a bit and I got it to work. Please submit an answer so that I can accept

Comment: You're looking for "eager" validation and the plugin is "lazy" by default.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment to the answer of Apple Orange, his/her solution shouldn't be used since you would submit the validated form too early in edge cases.

If you want to go the focus route, this would do the thing for you. With each `keyup` event, the submit button will be focused, then the input you were typing in will be refocused.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".name, .email").keyup(function(e){
   $('#sbt').focus();
    $(this).focus();
  });
  
  $("#form").validate({
      rules: {
          "name": {
              required: true,
              minlength: 5
          },
          "email": {
              required: true,
              email: true
          }
      },
      messages: {
          "name": {
              required: "Please, enter a name"
          },
          "email": {
              required: "Please, enter an email",
              email: "Email is invalid"
          }
      },
      submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
          alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
          return false; // for demo
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

input.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

label.error {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: red;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="name" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="email" />
    <button type="submit" id="sbt">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is also not how it's done.  You do not need to write a custom `keyup` function.  Simply use the built-in options of the plugin.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/25796775/594235

Comment: @Sparky your solution worked