# jquery validation plugin can't show up validation message for 'textarea' about maxlength

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

jQuery Validate plugin looks it cannot show up validation message for `textarea` about `maxlength` when the `textarea` is focused for the first time since the web page is reloaded.

The code is below, but if you want to check the code on a web browser, please check out the following the URL to JSFiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<form id="user-form" action="#">
  <label>comment: </label>
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment" required="" minlength="2" maxlength="20"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#user-form').validate({
    rules: {
      comment: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20
      }
    }
  })
})
</script>
<style>
.error {
  color: red;
}
</style>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s_kikuchi/afr7csp5/27/

Furthermore, I share the GIF which shows this problem, if you want to see it, please push the link below.

https://gyazo.com/e3b4273a5afd25fbd081f52e6a5b91fc

Comment: jQuery validation triggers on submit button/keypress so it will show error message if any activity happen. Do you want to show validation message if user exceed 20 character but still allow him to type? Explain a bit more

Comment: No idea what your issue is.  Your GIF is not showing the same as your jsFiddle, and your jsFiddle is working exactly as it should.   You do not need inline HTML5 validation when using the jQuery Validate plugin.  You essentially have the same rules declared twice.  For clarity and simplicity, just remove the HTML5 attributes in favor of the rules within `.validate()`.

Comment: It's possible that you're complaining about ["Lazy" validation where it will not validate until after the first click of the submit](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo).  Please read the docs and [search SO about how to implement "Eager" validation with this plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797083/594235).

Comment: Please see this jsFiddle and take note that only HTML is placed in the HTML pane, JavaScript is placed in the JavaScript pane, CSS is placed in the CSS pane, URL's to external resources are listed under resources, and jQuery 3.3.1 is selected as the JavaScript library.  https://jsfiddle.net/tps827db/

Comment: @Sparky
What I want to say with the GIF is the validation message is not shown when the textarea is focused.

In GIF, I did the following,
`
1. Focused textarea and typed characters more than 20.
2. Focused submit button
3. Focused and typed characters more than 20 again, then, validation message was shown up.
`

Comment: You are exactly describing Lazy validation.  See my second comment.