# jQuery validate would not work on focusout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following code to validate the input when focus out. What I want is whenever a user click the input field and click somewhere else to focus out, the field would validate itself to be not empty, and the message should be displayed. However the following code does not do anything when focused out.

```js
$("#NameQuery").on("focusout", function () {

  $("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
      NameQuery: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      NameQuery: "Please fill in name query"
    },
    errorElement : 'div',
    errorLabelContainer: '.error__input'
  });

});
```

```css
.error__input{
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
  <div class="error__input"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you need to initialise `validate()` when the page loads. To invoke the validation rules when the `focusout` event occurs, call the `valid()` method on the relevant `form`, like this:

```js
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query"
  },
  errorElement: 'div',
  errorLabelContainer: '.error__input'
});

$("#NameQuery").on("focusout", function() {
  $('#myform').valid();
});
```

```css
.error__input {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
  <div class="error__input"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe also mention in the answer that [validation with this plugin is "lazy" by default](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo).  Validation on blur is also the default after overcoming lazy validation on first click of submit.  [Otherwise, you can just force plugin to be "eager"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797083/594235).  In other words, you don't need a `focusout` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`onfocusout`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout) option

```js
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query"
  },
  onfocusout: function(element) {
    $(element).valid()
  },
  errorElement: 'div',
  errorLabelContainer: '.error__input'
});
```

```css
.error__input {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
  <div class="error__input"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```